# find the maximum value of $A$ satisfying the following inequality $3x^2+y^2+1\ge A(x^2+xy+x)$

Tags: number-theory, inequality, quadratics, discriminant

I would appreciate if somebody could help me with the following problem.

For any two natural numbers $x$,$y$, find the maximum value of $A$ satisfying the following inequality
$$3x^2+y^2+1\ge A(x^2+xy+x)$$
The above issue is the second round of the Korean secondary competition

My work : I tried to transform it into a quadratic equation for $x$ and use the discriminant to find it, but it is too difficult to interpret the discriminant under the condition that it is a natural number.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your idea works very well!

Indeed, let $x=y=1$.

Thus, $A\leq\frac{5}{3}.$

We'll prove that $\frac{5}{3}$ is a maximal value.

Let $x=1+a$ and $y=1+b$,where $a$ and $b$ are integers and $a\geq0$, $b\geq0.$

Thus, we need to prove that $$3b^2-(5a-1)b+4a^2-2a\geq0,$$ which is obvious for $a=0$.

Let $a\geq1$.

Thus, we need to prove that:
$$(5a-1)^2-12(4a^2-2a)\leq0$$ or $$23a^2-14a-1\geq0,$$ which is obvious again for $a\geq1$.

Comment: Thank you for answer. Why do you think x=y=1 in the first place?

Comment: +1 Very cute. ${}$

Comment: @Young It's the easiest  attempt  and  turned out that it works.